# Conversion of swc file to swf file?

Tags: flash, swc

How can we convert a swc file to swf file so that we can call the swf file whenever it is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Rename the `.swc` file to `.zip`.
2. Unzip it.
3. Copy `library.swf` from the archive and rename it how you like.